# Cobertura Runtime coverage on JBoss server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, cobertura

I was exploring on carrying out Cobertura code coverage for a Java web application at runtime and I came across an article http://www.mojohaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/instrumentingDeploymentArtifact.html

I followed the steps and was able to get coverage reports on a small maven web application where I deployed a war file ( containing a single module ) on JBoss server and manually browsed through the deployed application.

Now, when I followed the same procedure and steps for a bigger application where we need to deploy an ear file ( containing war file of several modules ) on the same setup and I manually hit the application services but I was unable to get any coverage for it. An empty cobertura.ser file is created initially but it doesn't get updated.

Please let me know if there is an issue with ear/war or anything else that needs to be configured in JBoss server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A known condition for Cobertura is that it writes the code coverage during JVM shutdown, i.e. it registers a shutdown hook, and dumps the info to the file at that time.
The problem is that JBoss usually halts the JVM before most shutdown hooks can execute, and that affects Cobertura.
See this FAQ: [I'm using JBoss. When I stop the server, the coverage data file is not written.](https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/wiki/FAQ#im-using-jboss-when-i-stop-the-server-the-coverage-data-file-is-not-written-or-the-coverage-data-file-is-0-bytes-or-cobertura-report-and-cobertura-merge-complain-that-the-coverage-data-file-is-invalid-possibly-throwing-an-eofexception)

The FAQ recommends using

```
  -Djboss.shutdown.forceHalt=false
```

Now, another common solution is to incorporate the CoberturaFlush.war (part of the distribution) into your EAR, and invoke a special url that will make the Cobertura runtime dump its data to the file. You'd want to invoke that url before shutting down your server/application, typically it's http://HOST:PORT**/coberturaFlush/flushCobertura**

One last thing: the data file will be generated in the working dir by default, so it's often safer to explicitly force a file pathname with:

```
 -Dnet.sourceforge.cobertura.datafile=[absolute file path]
```

In your case, that would have to be added to the JBoss startup parameters (e.g. run.conf)

Comment: on shutting down the JBoss server I get the below error.

10:45:58,693 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-67) Exception in thread "Thread-67" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.TouchCollector$ApplyToClassDataLightClassmapListener from class net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.TouchCollector

I am using cobertura-2.1.1.jar

Comment: Which of the two options were you trying ? If the former, it's possible that JBoss class unloading gets in the way, for instance if your cobertura jar is in the EAR, which is undeployed and classes unloaded before (or concurrently to?) the shutdown hook. The WAR solution may work better in this case, or instead try putting the Cobertura runtime jar in the jboss/server/main/lib/ folder.

Comment: I was able to remove the discussed error by downgrading the cobertura jar to cobertura-2.0.3.jar.  

Now, all the steps are working fine except that I am unable to gather the coverage data. I even tried -Djboss.shutdown.forceHalt=false as well as http://HOST:PORT/coberturaFlush/flushCobertura, but none of the steps succeeded.

Comment: Is there any log available when "things don't work" ? Or is it that whatever you try, that .ser file is just not generated ? Also, it could be that the file is generated at a different location than you'd expect I will augment the answer with that info.

Comment: the ser file was created somewhere else, i.e. in my case it was getting created in the folder structure similar to that of the build job ( **target/cobertura/cobertura.ser).

. the setup is working fine now.